How to call SetWinEventHook of win32 in flutter using ffi
I'm trying to monitor window show/hide events from other app using SetWinEventHook, but It doesn't seem to work after defining API function signature and calling it. I noticed a remark in the documentation stating that The client thread that calls SetWinEventHook must have a message loop in order to receive events. To address this, I added a message loop in Dart, but it caused the application to freeze.
How to fix it?
import 'dart:ffi';

import 'package:ffi/ffi.dart';
import 'package:win32/win32.dart';

// define constructs
const EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND = 3; // window activate
const EVENT_OBJECT_HIDE = 0x8000; // window minimize
const EVENT_OBJECT_SHOW = 0x8004; // window show
const EVENT_SYSTEM_MINIMIZESTART = 0x0016;
const WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT = 0x0000; 
const WINEVENT_SKIPOWNTHREAD = 0x0001; 
const WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS = 0x0002;

// define API function signature
typedef SetWinEventHookC = IntPtr Function(
  Uint32 eventMin, // lowest event value
  Uint32 eventMax, // highest event value
  IntPtr hmodWinEventProc, // DLL module handle
  Pointer<NativeFunction<WinEventProc>> lpfnWinEventProc, // callback
  Uint32 idProcess,
  Uint32 idThread,
  Uint32 dwFlags,
);

typedef SetWinEventHookDart = int Function(
  int eventMin, 
  int eventMax, 
  int hmodWinEventProc, 
  Pointer<NativeFunction<WinEventProc>> lpfnWinEventProc, 
  int idProcess, 
  int idThread, 
  int dwFlags,
);

typedef WinEventProc = Void Function(
  IntPtr hWinEventHook, 
  Uint32 eventType, 
  IntPtr hwnd, 
  Int32 idObject, 
  Int32 idChild, 
  Uint32 dwEventThread, 
  Uint32 dwmsEventTime,
);

typedef WinEventProcDart = void Function(
  int hWinEventHook, 
  int eventType, 
  int hwnd, 
  int idObject, 
  int idChild, 
  int dwEventThread, 
  int dwmsEventTime,
);

// load windows DLL
final user32 = DynamicLibrary.open('user32.dll');

// get SetWinEventHook function
final SetWinEventHookDart setWinEventHook = user32
    .lookupFunction<SetWinEventHookC, SetWinEventHookDart>('SetWinEventHook');

Call:
final ptr = NativeCallable<WinEventProc>.isolateLocal(winEventProc);
final hook = setWinEventHook(
  EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, 
  EVENT_OBJECT_SHOW,
  0,
  ptr.nativeFunction,
  0, // idProcess
  0, // idThread
  WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNTHREAD,
);

void winEventProc(int hWinEventHook, int eventType, int hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, int dwEventThread, int dwmsEventTime) {
  switch (eventType) {
    case EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND:
      print('A window was activated.');
      break;
    case EVENT_OBJECT_HIDE:
      print('A window was minimized.');
      break;
    case EVENT_OBJECT_SHOW:
      print('A window was restored from minimized state.');
      break;
    case EVENT_SYSTEM_MINIMIZESTART:
      print('A window is starting to minimize.');
      break;
    default:
      print('Other event triggered: $eventType');
  }
}

I've tried to start a message loop using Isolate.spawn or a async message loop to meet the requirements and avoid freezing. However, neither approach had any effect.
Isolate version:
void messageLoop(SendPort sendPort) {
  final msg = calloc<MSG>();
  while (true) {
    print('run');
    final result = GetMessage(msg, NULL, 0, 0);
    if (result == 0) break;
    DispatchMessage(msg);
  }
  sendPort.send('Done');
}

void startMessageLoop() async {
  final receivePort = ReceivePort();
  await Isolate.spawn(messageLoop, receivePort.sendPort);
  receivePort.listen((message) {
    if (message == 'Done') {
      print('Message loop finished.');
    }
  });
}

Async verison:
Future<void> startMessageLoop() async {
  final msg = calloc<MSG>();
  while (true) {
    print('run');
    final result = await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1), () => GetMessage(msg, NULL, 0, 0));
    print(result);
    if (result == 0) break;
    DispatchMessage(msg);
  }
}

